# What is the difference between the two use cases of using OpenID Connect in Keycloak? (Client vs Application)

Tags: authentication, oauth, authorization, keycloak, openid-connect

I am very new to the concepts of SSO and Keycloak. I am trying to read the official documentation of Keycloak. In the "Supported Protocols" part (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html), the documentation talks about the two use cases of using OIDC like this:

"The first is an application that asks the Keycloak server to authenticate a user for them. After a successful login, the application will receive an identity token and an access token. The identity token contains information about the user such as username, email, and other profile information. The access token is digitally signed by the realm and contains access information (like user role mappings) that the application can use to determine what resources the user is allowed to access on the application.

The second type of use cases is that of a client that wants to gain access to remote services. In this case, the client asks Keycloak to obtain an access token it can use to invoke on other remote services on behalf of the user. Keycloak authenticates the user then asks the user for consent to grant access to the client requesting it. The client then receives the access token. This access token is digitally signed by the realm. The client can make REST invocations on remote services using this access token. The REST service extracts the access token, verifies the signature of the token, then decides based on access information within the token whether or not to process the request."

What I do not understand is this: In the first paragraph it talks about an application making a request and in the second one it talks about a client. But aren't applications counted as clients? Why the specific differentiation? And can anyone given an example of the remote services that is talked about in the second part?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But aren't applications counted as clients? Why the specific differentiation? And can anyone given an example of the remote services that is talked about in the second part?

Yes exactly it. The reason for the differentiation is because there could be many applications more than just this one client. And the client, that the user is authed against may want to access all those other applications' data.

For example take the google ecosystem. Does google email have access to drive, and photos, etc... While it could out the box, it doesn't. You need to explicitly allow email "offline access" to those other applications, even though they are all part of the same platform.

Keycloak understands this and provides that terminology. But it is a bit confusing because this isn't the best way to think about it. Instead a better explanation is that there is just the user and service clients. The service clients all talk to each other and ask for a user's data. While a user may want their data by going straight to one application, other applications may want that user's data too.

Assuming you want to actually allow one service to ask for user data from another service, you want to be using something that supports authorization as a service and not just authentication. There are some examples of this, such as [PolicyServer](https://policyserver.com) and [Authress](https://authress.io).